# Ads showing up on the Salesforce Stack Exchange home page

Tags: discussion, support

Is anyone else getting add banners showing up on the Salesforce beta Stack Exchange pages?[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing any banners.

Comment: I think it is local to my device!

Comment: This is not coming from Stack Exchange - possibly an add-on/plugin misbehaving, or your ISP injecting them in.

Answer (score 8):

**Neververververvevreverververveverrrrrrrrr!**
<sup>*(that^ is a direct quote from our ad department)*</sup>

That ad is definitely not coming from Stack Exchange. We don't run invasive ads that get in your face and interfere with the content like that. It suspect that ad is either injected by your ISP or another extension that has been installed on your browser.

Answer (score 4):

I know that on some sites, ads are shown until some specific rep, didn't know/think we have it.

I would also check your browser add-ons